# Bash: Read a Text till end and split it on basis of a word

Tags: bash, text, while-loop, line

I have a text like

```
RECORD = ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ; jkjdkj@kjk.com ; END ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ; 
jkjdkj@kjk.com ; END kjkjlsj ; popo ; END
```

I want to split it up in 3 sentences. The splitting should be done on basis of reading till start till 'END' is encountered, then reading till next 'END' is encountered, and so on till end of the text

```
split 1 = ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ; jkjdkj@kjk.com ;
split 2 = ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ; jkjdkj@kjk.com ;
split 3 = kjkjlsj ; popo ;
```

Code I used is not able to utilize END . Can you please suggest ?

```
do
echo "$RECORD" | while read line
#Further processing on each of the split sentences

email=$(echo "$line" | awk -F ';' '{print $1}')
subject=$(echo "$line" | awk -F ';' '{print $2}')
body=$(echo "$line" | awk -F ';' '{print $3}')

echo "$body" | mail -s "$subject"  'sjhs@gmail.com';
#Further processing on each of the split sentences

done
fi
```

Comment: Why is `ijj%%% klfklk @ ;` not included as the beginning of split 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
$ s="ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ; jkjdkj@kjk.com ; END ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ; 
jkjdkj@kjk.com ; END kjkjlsj ; popo ; END" 

$ echo "$s" | tr -d '\n' | awk 'BEGIN{RS=" END ?"}1'
ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ; jkjdkj@kjk.com ; 
ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ; jkjdkj@kjk.com ; 
kjkjlsj ; popo ;
```

Turning a string delimited by `' END '` into a string delimited by `\n` can then be used in a bash loop for whatever you need to do to those substrings:

```
cnt=1
while read -r line; do
    printf "Line %s: %s\n" "$cnt" "'$line'"
    (( cnt++ ))
done <<<$(echo "$s" | tr -d '\n' | awk 'BEGIN{RS=" END ?"}1')
```

Prints:

```
Line 1: 'ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ; jkjdkj@kjk.com ;'
Line 2: 'ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ; jkjdkj@kjk.com ;'
Line 3: 'kjkjlsj ; popo ;'
```

If you want pure Bash, you could do:

```
delimit=" END "
s="${s//$'\n'}"
ss=$s$delimit
array=();
while [[ $ss ]]; do
    array+=( "${ss%%"$delimit"*}" );
    ss=${ss#*"$delimit"};
done;
```

Comment: Can this echo outputs be processed individually ?

Comment: Well yes. It has turned a string delimited by `'END '` into a string delimited by `\n`. You can now easily use a `\n` delimited string in many ways in Bash to process each of the individual strings.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure bash solution for this:

```sh
s="ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ; jkjdkj@kjk.com ; END ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ;
> jkjdkj@kjk.com ; END kjkjlsj ; popo ; END"

# enable extended glob
shopt -s extglob

# remove all newlines
s="${s//$'\n'}"

# replace " END" and an optional space with line break
s="${s// END?( )/$'\n'}"

# remove trailing line break and read in array arr
readarray -t arr <<< "${s%$'\n'}"

# examine array content
declare -p arr
```

**Output:**

```
declare -a arr=([0]="ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ; jkjdkj@kjk.com ;" [1]="ijj%%% klfklk @ ; kjkjkdjjd 333 ;> jkjdkj@kjk.com ;" [2]="kjkjlsj ; popo ;")
```

Comment: Thank you very much ...i'll try it out